# Can I program a garage key without rendering other programmed keys useless?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

At my previous residence, I used to press a `program/reset` button on the garage motor to program a new remote. But that used to also make any other remotes paired to it useless as those remotes would need to be paired/programmed at the same instance. I may have been doing it the wrong way, I don't know.

Now at my current residence, the remote I was given by the real estate agent (ATA PTX-5) is absolutely dodgy (doesn't work sometimes), and recently the key-holder part broke making it independent and separate to my key bunch, making it easily misplaced.

I have the garage remote I used at my previous residence and wish to pair it to this current garage. I haven't looked at the brand on the garage motor, but thought I would ask if it's possible to pair this remote to the garage motor without 'breaking' the other remotes used by the other residents?

Comment: What brand and model is the opener itself? Typically, the answer is no. This way, someone cannot sneak in to add a remote without the owner knowing.

Comment: The opener is ATA PTX-5. It looks pretty much like a generic multi-use remote.

Comment: You need to tell us the make/model of the door operator itself, not the broken remote.

Comment: @Tyson right, I thought Doxy was asking for the opener/remote model. As for the motor model, I do not know as yet. Will check and update.

Comment: The remote appears to be a universal remote, how the program button works is dependent on the make/model of the opener itself.  If part of your answer is liftmaster or chamberlain also tell us the color of the programming button itself (it tells frequency and rolling code scheme being utilized).

Comment: @Tyson absolutely, I'll include those details when I get to the gate...